# Using Testing Library in standalone

Tags: javascript, testing-library

I was trying to do something similar to the [Testing Playground](https://testing-playground.com/) but I don't know which JavaScript file to include to have access to all the [Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/) native functions.

The goal is to be able to run queries like `getAllByRole` in the browser console. I don't want to have a Node project running. I just want a basic HTML file that includes the Testing Library JavaScript file so I can run its functions in the browser console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start without any bundle tools, try the `@testing-library/dom` library from the `skypack` CDN which prepares npm packages for native JavaScript ES6 import usage. (It's the one being used in codepen.io)

```html
<script type="module">
  import { getByRole } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/@testing-library/dom@7.29.6"; 
  console.log(getByRole)
</script>
```

Comment: I wonder if there's a version I can copy and paste into my console.  the goal is to use it here: https://github.com/lsoares/selenium-testing-library

Comment: for the purpose above, I can't use any URLs to import (or I bump into CSP issues). I managed to put it working with a script version from the Testing Playground Chrome plugin... but apparently, it's old... :(